# How to make up some check box look as if it's disabled

Tags: html, css, web

Which attribute of input tag I should set to make up below check box look as if it's disabled.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedUsers" value="gng"  />
```

However, I don't want to use "disabled" attribute to really disable it because I want its value submitted to web server.

More details:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedUsers" value="user1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedUsers" value="user2"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedUsers" value="user3"  />
```

I have a list of users and check box to indicate whether it has editor role. System allows admin change user's roles by checking boxes and hit a button Confirm. Then Web server will check variables "selectedUsers" to see the list of user are checked, and do a comparation with role values of users from database. If server sees the difference, it will do appropriate actions, either delete or add editor's role of that users from a database table.

For example, user1 is not on variable "selectedUsers" but in database table, it has this role, so system understands that the admin want to delete editor role of that user, and vice versa.

However, some users are already admin users, hence I don't allow other admin can change these users roles, just able to see its roles. So I want check boxes for these admin users appearing to be disabled. I can't use: disabled="disabled" because if I really disable a checkbox, the user of this checkbox **always** be excluded from variable "selectedUsers".

Update after 5 hours:

I'm able to change UI to not allow client to modify check box as below. Clients can click on checkbox but check box doesn't change their value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedUsers" value="amdin1" onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false" />
```

The current problem is to find a way to indicate client that the website don't want them to check/uncheck boxes. That way I want this check box look immutable (somehow by changing background color, ...).

Comment: Usually when something is disabled, it's not meant to be sent. Why would you want to send a disabled control? Maybe there's a better way. Please include **WHAT** you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your updated question, you're making a wrong decision here.

Disallowing one user to edit some other users access rights is a **business logic**. Implementing it by "disabling" the checkboxes is like preventing the prisoners from escaping by only the "do not pass" sign.

You **must** do the appropriate checks (namely, checking that no access rights were changed for users which current user is disallowed to manage) on the server side just for the reasons of security. This is the **first** thing to do.

**Additionally**, you might want to implement your UI so that it will be more convenient for users (aka "do not pass" sign before the security check-point). The best solution would be to simply disable the checkboxes. The peculiarity of such a solution of that it won't send disabled checkboxes values should not bother you, as you **already** should ignore any values for such users on a server side.

Comment: I just describe a very similar situation of my real and complex problem, not exactly reflect it. I understand your concern in last paragraph. However, if I really disable check box for admin users. These users's name will be excluded from variable "selectedUsers" as I mentioned on the question. So server will think that edit roles of these users is supposed to be deleted and do it. That's an unexpected behavior.

Comment: @bnguyen82 , i don't see how your update changes our answers. If you want checkboxes to appear immutable to your users, then just **make** checkboxes immutable by using `disabled` attribute. Also, according to your first update, you anyway don't need to process the values of disabled checkboxes.

Comment: Also, reading your question again, i suggest you to use radio buttons (`<input type="radio" .../>`) instead of checkboxes. Unchecked checkboxes values are not sent to the server for a reason: the checkboxes are meant to provide the way of getting list of items user has checked, not the list of items they have unchecked. Consider e.g. the following scenario: user opens the page with checkboxes; in the same time, some other user creates a new user with some access rights; first user modifies the access rights, submits the page, and voila, all access rights of the new user are reset.

Comment: This scenario you mentioned is reasonable although it might rarely happens with this kind of our admin screen. Anyway, thanks for your answer, I need to review the current design before moving on.

Comment: The user must **explicitly** state they want to give or take some access rights, and you must process only the explicitly stated information (i.e. the value that has been submitted to you, not the fact that some value has **not** been submitted to you). Even if you want to implement it with checkboxes, then you still should send the explicit "on"/"off" data to the server; you may implement it e.g. with the hidden fields and javascript gathering the states of checkboxes to the said fields.

Answer (score 3):

If you want checkbox to be shown as disabled, but in the same time want its content to be sent, you can create an `<input type=hidden .../>` field with an appropriate name and value and disable the checkbox.

If the checkbox value or state are changed dynamically, then we can rely on the browser scripting support (or else value / state change would not work), and change the hidden field value in the same place we're changing the state of the checkbox.

Comment: @bnguyen82 First, my answer fits your updated question as well. Second, i also posted a detailed explanation of why you should not want to do what you're asking about in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible: The native "disabled" look is rendered by the browser and usually not achievable through CSS styling.

The only workaround that I can see is

- Setting the checkbox to `disabled="disabled"`
- Using JavaScript, enabling it when the form gets sent

this of course will work only if JavaScript is enabled, so it's not watertight. It's probably best to re-think what you want to achieve.

Comment: That all depends on how far you're willing to go, you'll usually need JavaScript (or jQuery) with CSS styling, which I don't like.

Comment: @Truth yeah, plus you won't be able to achieve the *native* "disabled" look which varies from browser to browser and from OS to OS. Doing that 100% is virtually impossible even with jQuery. (I added a workaround idea though)

Comment: Is there any trick (background color, opacity..) to create relatively similar effect.

Comment: @bnguyen82 no, because the look of disabled elements will differ from client to client depending on the OS. Do check out my edit though

Comment: @Pekka I don't need a real disabled feel. I just need an effect to indicate client that this check box is simply immutable.

Comment: @bnguyen if you control the whole page, I don't see why you can't show a truly disabled control, and store the value in a hidden field if necessary? Like penartur suggests.